# Questions about CBP and also UK immigration

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration

1. I'm going to visit my fiancee in the USA for 16 days next month. We got engaged last time I was over in May 2019. Now, we still use the term boyfriend/girlfriend (don't know exactly why, just do. Dislike the fiance/e term!). Upon immigration, should I explain I'm visiting a girlfriend, or a fiancee, once they ask the purpose of my visit? I don't know whether to just point out that although we're engaged I still refer to her as my girlfriend.

We're marrying in the States later this year then applying for a UK Spousal Visa afterwards with intent on moving to the UK. I am employed there and have a good job.

2. On a related note, if I'm admitted to the USA, I'm going to pay for her flight to come back to the UK with me in early August so we can fly back together. Now that American citizens can use ePassport gates at UK airports, would the fact she was refused entry last time prevent her from using one of these automated points? She has since applied for a standard visitor visa and received it last month.

Additionally, am I able to stand with her in the non-EU immigration line, or should I just use the British citizens line and wait for her on the other side?

Many thanks.

Comment: It may be better to ask two separate questions, since they involve different immigration systems and circumstances. Will you already be married when she tries to visit in August?

Comment: No we'll still be engaged.

Answer (score 2):

Re: 2. It's not possible to guess the effect of her previous refusal.

However, you can both try the E-gates on arrival in the UK. If her passport is rejected, she will be sent to speak to an Immigration Officer. You can either go with her or go through the E-gates and wait behind the desk (not on the Officer's shoulder).

When your g/f is speaking to the Officer she can suggest that you come forward to assist in explaining the circumstances.

To add, the queues are not EU or Non-EU now. With E-gates open to more nationalities, those eligible to use E-gates but accompanied by children under 12 years old; or unaccompanied people under 18 years old - all queue together (UK, EU USA, Canada etc). There is a separate queue for nationalities that cannot use E-gates.

Comment: Ok thank you. We'll try to use an E-gate but I suspect because she was refused entry last year it'll flag her up for manual inspection, to which she'll have to show her visit visa and answer the IO's questions.